# Connecting to React docker container on port 80

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy a React app as part of a docker compose. It works fine if I deploy on port 3000, but when I use port 80, I cannot connect. If I run `npm start` manually, either config works fine, but I cannot access the port 80 version when running as a docker image.

I've tried adding `EXPOSE 80` to the dockerfile, but it did not seem to have any effect. Can someone point out the error in my config?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:17-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@5.0.0 -g

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  solvle:
    build: ./
    container_name: solvle_c
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
  solvle_front:
    build: ./solvle-front
    container_name: solvle_front_c
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

**package.json fragment**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=80 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/assign-port-docker-container

Comment: Are you attempting to access the app in the container in the same way as you are when using `npm start`? Eg, if you access the app via `localhost` when using `npm start`, are you still using `localhost` when it is in the container?

Comment: It can be a good idea to double check that dockerized react app really listen to 80 port inside docker container. You may try starting docker container with React interactively and see console output. Most probably you'll see what port React app will listen. `docker run -it <image name from docker build>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linux you should set port in this way:

```
"start": "export PORT=80 && react-scripts start"
```

Another solution is create a file with name `.env` ([documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/4cdd5ac/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#advanced-configuration)) in the main directory and set `PORT` variable to desired port number:

```
PORT=80
```

One more solution.
You could use [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) to set the port:

```
npm install cross-env -D
```

and then modify start script `package.json`:

```
"start": "cross-env PORT=80 react-scripts start",
```

p.s.
But for deploy react app with docker I woud recomend you to use nginx.

p.p.s.
The `EXPOSE` instruction in dockerfile does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation.  [expose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

Comment: Thank you, this was totally the problem. My dev environment was in windows, so I was using SET PORT=80, but I needed to export for docker. I will have to pursue one of the other solutions to support both, but this explains why 3000 was working (since it was the default).